# Why itext7 for .NET uses (much) more memory than itextsharp5?

Tags: c#, .net, itext, pdf-generation

I am using itext for generating PDFs on a .NET environmet. Trying to optimize execution time I am migrating from itextsharp  5.5.13 to itext 7.1.1 for .NET.

The generated PDF consist mainly on images. I generate documents on parallel with multi threading.

itext7 seems faster but memory usage is much higher. Since I am generating more than one document at the same time I run out of memory.

I ran a simple test with the same input data and the output file is 5 MB. Below is my code for both versions of the library. It is something wrong with my code?

**itextsharp 5**

Time: 1:18, RAM: peak 173MB an then steady around 65MB

```
public string GenerateImagesReport(IEnumerable<IChartData> data, string basename)
    {
        var doc = PdfUtility.CreateDoc();

        string path = Shared.BuildPdfPath(basename);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

            float left = 30f;
            float bottom = PdfUtility.GetYPosition(ReportElem.Chart2);
            float width = PdfUtility.CHART_WIDTH;
            float heigth = PdfUtility.CHART_hEIGTH * 2 + PdfUtility.V_SPACE1 + PdfUtility.V_SPACE2 + PdfUtility.GROUP_BY;

            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Open();
            PdfTemplate ImageTemplate;
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            Image img;
            foreach (var chart in data)
            {
                // chart image
                ImageTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(width, heigth);
                img = Image.GetInstance(chart.ImageBytes, true);
                img.ScaleAbsolute(width, heigth);
                img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
                ImageTemplate.AddImage(img);

                cb.AddTemplate(ImageTemplate, left, bottom);

                chart.DestroyImage();
                doc.NewPage();
            }
            doc.Close();
        }

        return path;
    }
```

**itext 7**

Time: 1:09, RAM: peak 753MB steady to the end

```
public string GenerateImagesReport(IEnumerable<IChartData> data, string basename)
    {
        string path = Shared.BuildPdfPath(basename);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fs);
            var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            var pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
            var doc = new Document(pdf, pageSize);

            float left = 30f;
            float bottom = PdfUtility.GetYPosition(ReportElem.Chart2);
            float width = PdfUtility.CHART_WIDTH;
            float heigth = PdfUtility.CHART_hEIGTH * 2 + PdfUtility.V_SPACE1 + PdfUtility.V_SPACE2 + PdfUtility.GROUP_BY;

            PdfPage page;
            PdfCanvas canvas;
            ImageData imgd;
            Image img;
            page = pdf.AddNewPage();
            foreach (var chart in data)
            {
                canvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true);

                imgd = ImageDataFactory.Create(chart.ImageBytes);
                img = new Image(imgd, left, bottom);
                img.ScaleAbsolute(width, heigth);

                new Canvas(canvas, pdf, pageSize)
                    .Add(img);

                chart.DestroyImage();
                page = pdf.AddNewPage();
            }

            doc.Close();
        }

        return path;
    }
```

**Update**

I am using Visual Studio Profiler to monitor memory usage. Following Yaroslav Veremenko input, I am seeing an improvement on memory usage. Different chart have marked when the actual process of generating pdf starts.

*with itextsharp 0:43*
[image: itextsharp memory usage]

*with itext7 0:26*
[image: itext7 memory usage]

*with itext7 - page.Flush() 0:42*
[image: itext7 memory usage 2]

Comment: iText QA here. I disagree with the close vote. The question is very clear and contains code examples. The answers are also very high quality. I am marking the question as favorite and will come back to it later. Being a Linux guy myself, I don't have a lot of experience with performance monitoring in Windows, but I'll port the code to Java and see how it behaves on Linux. I may ask additional questions in the comments.

Comment: First question: how exactly did you measure memory usage?

Comment: If this question gets closed, please let me know so that I can vote to reopen it. I agree with Amedee's comment: good question.

Comment: I ported the code to Java and the memory consumption is about the same. More than 1000MB for a 500 pages document with two images per page. @AmedeeVanGasse

Comment: I haven't had the time for it yet, but I haven't forgotten about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library, but it could be `PdfCanvas` and `Canvas` objects not being destroyed after being used, and sitting in the memory until the document is destroyed. 
According to the documentation you must release the memory after drawing the chart.

> Make sure to call PdfCanvas.release() after you finished writing to
>   the canvas.

Source: https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/dd5c209cff35c137ed451fef6e11a96889a52fe9/itext/itext.kernel/itext/kernel/pdf/canvas/PdfCanvas.cs#L69

**UPD**

I just ran it locally. In my example I had peak on 500MB. After I added:

```
page.Flush(true);
```

It dropped to 250MB.

*Reference: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.2/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfPage.html#flush-boolean-*

**UPD2**

Memory usage with and without `page.Flush(true)`

```
    foreach (var chart in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        canvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true);
        imgd = ImageDataFactory.Create((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(data, typeof(byte[])));
        img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(imgd, left, bottom);
        img.ScaleAbsolute(width, heigth);
        new Canvas(canvas, pdf, pageSize)
            .Add(img);
        // this line has been added
        page.Flush(true);
        page = pdf.AddNewPage();
    }
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Not working. Also tried with no difference:

bool immediateFlush = true;
new Canvas(canvas, pdf, pageSize, immediateFlush)
                        .Add(img);

Comment: @sillo01 let me know if it works for you, I am kind of curious now

Comment: Memory usage looks proportional to the pages/images added. I will let you the results following the update.

Comment: How exactly did you measure memory usage?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I was using dotMemory

Answer (score 1):

The big one would be to wrap `PdfWriter` in a `using` as this implements `IDisposable` for a reason and should help hugely when used in parallel. I've also removed the instantiation of `Canvas` as it seems unnecessary and wasteful when your existing `PdfCanvas` object can do the same thing. Also, I've moved your fields into the `Foreach` scope so they have a higher chance of collection by the GC.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fs)) //**Implements IDisposable - This should help hugely when used in Parallel**
    {
         var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
         var pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;
         var document = new Document(pdf);

          foreach (var chart in data)
          {
             var page = pdf.AddNewPage(); //When it get's reassigned on the next iteration, Garbage collection will take over
             PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page, true); //When it get's reassigned on the next iteration, Garbage collection will take over
             canvas.AddImage(ImageDataFactory.Create(chart.ImageBytes), pageSize, false); //1x Less Object in Memory but you will need to play around with params for precision.
             chart.DestroyImage();
          }

          document.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still think that `PdfCanvas` should be released manually as per documentation, event if GC can do it later. It would not hurt, anyway. As per my answer, the biggest memory usage was keeping the whole document in the memory. After flushing the page to the disk by `page.Flush(true)`, memory usage dropped at least in half.

Comment: Do you mean `Release()` for `PdfCanvas`? If so then yeah, it may help...my biggest concern was the instantiation of the new object  (`Canvas`) which duplicated memory along with not calling `Dispose()` on the `PdfWriter` which holds the entire document. That right there should make a huge saving.

Comment: Using page.Flush(true) makes significant improvement on memory usage. However itextsharp performs much better for me.